# Provide data from AuthProvider to store in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I've been working on a project with React and Firebase Auth recently. I got now stuck because I can't access the firebase user data from other classes. I've read about lifting the state and relationship between classes but nothing seems to be right.

If you need more code come ahead!

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AuthProvider>
                <Router>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Header />
                        <Route path="/" component={Feed}>
```

Auth.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import app from "./firebase";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
}, []);

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
};
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem with returning not only {{children}} from the AuthProvider. I return my Header with the currentUser as props.
I'm open to better solutions!